# how can i return 305274961 from 123456789 using my function

Tags: javascript

if we take for example n=123456789 i need to return 305274961 I get it by add 2 to the 1,3,5... and subtracting 2 to the 2,4,6.... I've done that using for loops and some arrays but now i need to combine the two arrays and then join them using the .join(' ') function

```
function encryptMyCode(n) {

var spell = n.toString(10).split('')
    var arr1 =[]
    var arr2 =[]

    for(var i=0 ; i<spell.length; i=i+2){
        arr1.push((parseInt(spell[i])+2)%10);
    }
    for(var i=1 ; i<spell.length; i=i+2){
        arr2.push(Math.floor(parseInt(spell[i]-2)%10));
    }

    // if n = 123456789
    // arr1 = [ 3, 5, 7, 9, 1 ]
    // arr2 = [ 0, 2, 4, 6 ]
    // i want to return[3,0,5,2,7,4,9,6,1]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `i % 2` inside a single loop, and push while adding or subtracting based on the result:

```js
function encryptMyCode(n) {
  const inputArr = n.toString(10).split('');
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
    result.push((Number(inputArr[i]) + (i % 2 ? -2 : 2)) % 10);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(encryptMyCode(123456789));
```

Or, with `.map`, which looks a bit cleaner:

```js
function encryptMyCode(n) {
  return n
    .toString(10)
    .split('')
    .map((num, i) => (Number(num) + (i % 2 ? -2 : 2)) % 10);
}
console.log(encryptMyCode(123456789));
```

Comment: thanks bro, but i need the last 11 to be jus 1 i used the mod(10) in my code how can i do it in yours

Comment: Put the `% 10` outside the addition, on the right

Comment: Please note the above uses the index not the number to do the modulus. Saying if you call encryptMyCode(333) it will return 515, not 555. To use the number you can do 
`function encryptMyCode(n){ return parseInt(Array.from(String(n), Number).map(i => (i+= i%2 ? 2: -2) % 10).join(''), 10); }` Also note that encryptMyCode(22),  encryptMyCode(2222)  encryptMyCode(2222222) will all return 0

Comment: @JakobE I'm pretty sure that adding or subtracting depending on the index is what OP wants - that's the logic he's implementing in his original code (just without the zipping together of the arrays)

Comment: You could be right – it was just in case it wasn't  :)